# Conserve current route and pop previous one in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter package the shows a notification to the user pushing a new route on top of the stack.
I would like to keep my notification's route on top if the user presses the back button on Android or uses a back gesture on IOS and pop the previous route instead.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible to do. However, you can show a non-route notification above the whole screen content, and it won't be dismissed on pop. Is that feasible in your context? I could show you how to implement that.

Comment: I did not know that was possible. And yes, I think it would solve my problems. If you could just point the direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`Notification`:

```dart
class Notification {
  static OverlayEntry _overlayEntry;

  static void show({
    @required NotificationWidget notification,
    @required BuildContext context,
  }) {
    final OverlayState overlay =
        context.rootAncestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<OverlayState>());

    _overlayEntry = _buildOverlayEntry(notification);

    overlay.insert(_overlayEntry);
  }

  static OverlayEntry _buildOverlayEntry(NotificationWidget notification) {
    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (_) {
        return Positioned(
          left: 8,
          top: 32,
          right: 8,
          child: notification,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  static void hide() {
    if (_overlayEntry != null) {
      _overlayEntry.remove();
      _overlayEntry = null;
    }
  }
}
```

`NotificationWidget`:

```dart
class NotificationWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String description;

  NotificationWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.description,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 4,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              title,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 4),
            Text(
              description,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To show or hide, the user can write:

```dart
void showNotification() {
  Notification.show(
    context: context,
    notification: NotificationWidget(
      title: 'Notification title',
      description: 'Notification description',
    ),
  );
}

void hideNotification() => Notification.hide();
```

`Notification` and `NotificationWidget` could be a single class, but I think it's better this way. Also, the user can easily create his/hers custom notification by overriding `NotificationWidget`.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the boilerplate code making it easy for the user to show a notification. While this works, it is still not what I'm looking for. I will make some experiments with the Overlay widget and get back to you afterward.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Using a `Overlay` is actually a great idea. I though overlays also created a route, but I was wrong. In case you haven't found a solution yet, please take a look at my edit. To show or hide the notification, no setup is required, it's as simple as calling a method, so I think this may be appropriate to you.